# hive compatible not in syntax with version 0.10 and CDH4.3

Tags: hive, hiveql

how to write a hive syntax equivalent to NOT IN using version 0.10. The where clause does not supports sub selects within the IN statement

Answer (score 0):

Subselects for NOT IN won't be available until Hive 13.